# Why do people purchase website themes?

Tags: wordpress, themes

I am a newbie in Web designing. I learnt about templates that are available online that people can purchase and change the content according to their requirements.

One thing puzzled me. Why do people purchase themes when they can copy the code using VIEW SOURCE option. I have tried searching the answer but google has failed me.

Also, If I am not using Wordpress, can still I use Wordpress themes for my website.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Because, while often technologically possible, that's still copyright infringement.
2. Because WordPress themes usually are more than just their raw HTML/CSS/JS. The PHP logic is frequently pretty complex and important.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Copying source code is stealing. If you're copying the html/css, you'll probably copy the images, too. Definitely could be legal issues in that.

2.) If you decide to try and steal it anyways, you'll notice in a lot of cases they've used Iframes or JavaScript to pull the code in from elsewhere, where you do not have access to it.

3.) Copying CSS and HTML wouldn't do much for a Wordpress site. You wont' be able to copy any of the server-side stuff.

4.) You can't really use the theme because a Wordpress theme comes with functions and much more. You could use the CSS with a lot of hacking.

Answer (score -2):

We can only copy the Html form either full encoding of the sites ie, ref style sheet. 
According to the law, copy web design structure, encoding is a crime and Definitely could be legal issues in that.
If you are a newbie in web designing, I suggest you some of the top web designing blog that you should follow.

https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/web-design-tips
 https://blog.techreshape.com/5-web-design-tips-for-a-better-website-user-experience/